# Редактирование ячейки

Tags: java, swing

Доброго времени суток! Как можно при редактировании ячейки jtable (когда пользователь вводит значения в ячейку) ограничить вводимые значения - т.е. чтобы нельзя было ввести отрицательное число и т.д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть такая вещь, как CellEditor, то  в качестве него используй JFormattedTextField, к нему можно приделать верификатор, то бишь нечто расширяющее класс InputVerifier, который будет как раз проверять введенные значения.